# Towers game strategy

Tags: game-theory

Given the following game, what is the strategy to win?

Given $N$ towers of different heights. Two players play against each other. Each player (in his turn) divides each of the towers which are greater than 1 into two separate towers. The player who wins is the one that after his (last) turn all towers are of height 1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A Combinatorial Game Riddle - two players dividing towers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4443799/a-combinatorial-game-riddle-two-players-dividing-towers)

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with [Nim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim)?  As an impartial game, this is Nim in disguise.  You need to figure out which positions are $N$ (wins for the next player) and $P$ (wins for the previous player).  You only care about the largest stack because each player has to play in all stacks greater than $1$.  A largest stack of size $1$ is $P$ by the rules.  $2$ plays to $1$ and wins, so is $N$.  $3$ has to leave a $2$, so is $P$. $4$ can move to $3$ and win, so is $N$.  Keep going a while and try to find a pattern.

Comment: See also [this Nim question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457360/splitting-stacks-nim), which is very similar.

Comment: Also, if each player were choosing a single tower to split on every turn, then the game would be [Grundy's game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grundy%27s_game), for which a complete solution has yet to be found. In this case, though, every large tower is split, so the game is different.

Comment: I've read the Nim question, I don't know how to use it though with my problem

Comment: I've read the Nim question, I don't know how to use it though with my problem

Comment: Can you figure out who wins for $5,6,7,8$?

Comment: the first player?

Comment: Not for all of them.

Comment: for 5 and 7 - the first player, for 6 and 8- the second player?

Comment: No.  What can $5$ move to?  Are any of the choices a win for him, the previous player?  Having done $5$ you have the information to do $6$ and so on.

Comment: 5 can be 2+3 or 1+4. for "2+3", 2=1+1, 3=2+1 so the first player wins. for "1+4", 4=1+3 or 4=2+2 . for "4=1+3" the second player wins. for "4=2+2" the first player wins.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19324/discussion-between-ross-millikan-and-ms93).

Comment: I tried to go to chat, but it didn't work.  I said at the start we only care about the largest stack, so 5 can go to 3 or 4.  Since we already said moving to 3 is a win, 5 is N, a first player win.  6 can also move to 3, so is N as well.

Comment: So I understand that for 3, 7=(3+4), 15=(7+8), 31=(15+16), 63=(31+32) and so on... the second player wins. How I use it for the largest stack? What do I need to check in order to decide if it is in the list bellow? Is there a condition on N?

Comment: You are right.  The second player wins when the largest stack is of the form $2^n-1$  To prove this, we need to show that given a largest stack of the form $2^n-1$ after two moves the second player can ensure that the largest stack is now $2^{n-1}-1$.  To do that, we need to show that the second player can always generate such a stack and that all the products of smaller stacks can be made at most that.  If one stack is $2^n-1$, one of the ones the first player leaves must be at least $2^{n-1}$ so the second player can leave a stack of $2^{n-1}-1$ .

Comment: Any stack of size $2^n-2$ or less, the second player will be able to cut to $2^{n-1}-1$ or less.

Comment: This is NOT Nim in disguise. Nowhere in the solution to this game is the nim sum employed. Impartial games are only nim in disguise when you play in _exactly one_ component game at a time, but here we play in _all nonterminal_ components.